# SQL aggregate function returning inflated values on joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm breaking my head here where I'm going wrong.
The following query:

```
SELECT SUM(table1.col1) FROM table1
```

returns value *x*.

And the following query:

```
SELECT SUM(table1.col1) FROM table2 RIGHT OUTER JOIN table1 ON table2.ID = table1.ID
```

returns value *y*. (I need the Join for the other data of table2). Why is the 2nd example returning a different value than in the first?

Comment: Does it have to be a Right/Left outer Join?  What about just a simple JOIN?

Comment: I need the full join. an inner join doesn't return all values from table 1.

Comment: try using SELECT SUM(table1.col1) FROM table2 RIGHT OUTER JOIN table1 ON table2.ID = table1.ID group by table1.ID

Comment: if you are summing values from table1, why do you need table2? The answer should provide insight into how to structure the query.

Comment: By grouping it, I lose the purpose of aggregation, and I also can't check if there is no redundancies.

Comment: what DBMS you're using? Is it mysql, sql-server, or any?

Comment: @turophile I need the values from table2. I just didn't include it in the posted question for clarity. The result is still the same whether I include the table 2 data, or not

Comment: @rigel it is SQL Server

Comment: Then why don't you try the full join?

Comment: You should ask the real question then, otherwise people could waste their time on what might be an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 3):

Make life easier on yourself, your colleagues that will support your code, and your clients by temporarily ignoring the existence of RIGHT OUTER JOIN. Use Table1 as the "from table" instead of table2.

Then, If aggregating, you will often find it necessary to do this BEFORE joining, so that the numbers are accurate. e.g.

```
SELECT T1.SUMCOL1 
FROM (
      SELECT id, SUM(col1) as SUMCOL1 FROM Table1 GROUP BY id
     ) T1
LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 T2 on T1.id = T2.ID
```

Answer (score 2):

Obvious answer is because `table2` is many to `table1`'s one.  That is, there are multiple rows in `table2` for one id in `table1`.  You may also be eliminating rows from `table1` if the `id` isn't present in `table2`.

Compare:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1
```

To:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 RIGHT OUTER JOIN table1 ON table2.ID = table1.ID
```

If you get different results, you're aggregating duplicates or eliminating rows from `table1`.

If you want to avoid this, you'll need to use a subquery.

Comment: That is correct. So how can I sum up the duplicates

Comment: @yankygo I would probably use a subquery.  It's not clear, though, if you want to total of `table1` or the total of `table1` for rows which exist in `table2`.

Comment: I want to total of 'table1'